# Android App is crashing when using AsyncTask execute method

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-studio, android-asynctask

My app contains class called BackgroundWorker that extends AsyncTask for handling communication with online server.
I'm trying to activate the backgroundWorker class from two different classes -  one is from my MainActivity class and the other is from Register class.
When running the following lines:

```
BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker(MainActivity.this);
bgw.execute(type , username , password);
```

from the MainActivity class - everything works great but when trying to run them from the other class i.e Register class like this:

```
 BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker(Register.this);
 bgw.execute(type ,name, surname, age, username , password);
```

The app crashes with following pop-up message:

> Unfortunately, APPNAME has stopped

I know that it's the

> bgw.execute()

line that causes this because I debugged the program.

Here is my full code of the 2 classes:

**MainActivity** (where the execute method works perfectly):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText etUser;
    EditText etPass;
    Button btnLogin;
    Button btnRegister;
    TextView tvStatus;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_username);
        etPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_password);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_login);

        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_reg);

        onLoginClick();
        onRegisterClick();
    }

    public void onLoginClick() {
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String username = etUser.getText().toString();
                String password = etPass.getText().toString();
                String type = "login";
                BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker(MainActivity.this);
                bgw.execute(type , username , password);

            }
        });
    }
    public void onRegisterClick() {
        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent openRegisterActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this , Register.class);
                startActivity(openRegisterActivity);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Register class** (Where the execute make the app crash):

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnSubmit;
    EditText etName;
    EditText etSurname;
    EditText etAge;
    EditText etUsername;
    EditText etPassword;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_submit);
        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_name);
        etSurname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_surname);
        etAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_age);
        etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_username);
        etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_password);


        onSubmit();
    }
    public void onSubmit() {
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = etName.getText().toString();
                String surname = etSurname.getText().toString();
                String age = etAge.getText().toString();
                String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
                String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
                String type = "Register";

                BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker(Register.this);
                bgw.execute(type ,name, surname, age, username , password);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and I don't think that it's relevant to the crash but anyway here is my **BackgroundWorker class** (That extends AsyncTask) code:

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask <String , Integer , String> {
    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    public BackgroundWorker(Context userContext) {
        this.context = userContext;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // STACK OVERFLOW SAY TO PUT THIS FOR DUBUG
        if(android.os.Debug.isDebuggerConnected())
            android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();

        // Reading the arguments in the order I sent them in MainActivity
        String type = params[0];

        // Making structure for updating during the wat using Toasts (and showing the first one
        int progressValue = 0;          // Before if
        publishProgress(progressValue);
        // Initial String that will hold the text to read from server
        String result = "";
        // Initial the URL String
        String loginURL = "http://noche.netai.net/login.php";
        String registerURL = "http://noche.netai.net/register.php";
        if (type.equals("login")) {

            String username = params[1];
            String password = params[2];

            progressValue++;    //1
            publishProgress(progressValue);

            try {
                URL url = new URL(loginURL);

                progressValue++;    //2
                publishProgress(progressValue);

                // Building the HttpUrlConnection object
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

                progressValue++;    //3
                publishProgress(progressValue);

                // Building the writing infrastructure
                // IOException occurs after the commit of the next line
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));

                progressValue++;    //4
                publishProgress(progressValue);

                // Building the message to the PHP script
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name" , "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username , "UTF-8")
                        + "&" + URLEncoder.encode("user_pass" , "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password , "UTF-8");

                progressValue++;    //5
                publishProgress(progressValue);

                // Writing the data
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);

                progressValue++;    //6
                publishProgress(progressValue);

                // Closing all writing structures
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();

                // Building the Reading Infrastructure
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream , "iso-8859-1"));

                // Reading the data
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                // Closing all reading structures
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                progressValue = 10;
                publishProgress(progressValue);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                progressValue = 11;
                publishProgress(progressValue);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (type.equals("register")) {

            String name = params[1];
            String surname = params[2];
            String age = params[3];
            String username = params[4];
            String password = params[5];

            progressValue++;    //1
            publishProgress(progressValue);

            try {
                URL url = new URL(registerURL);

                progressValue++;    //2
                publishProgress(progressValue);

                // Building the HttpUrlConnection object
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

                progressValue++;    //3
                publishProgress(progressValue);

                // Building the writing infrastructure
                // IOException occurs after the commit of the next line
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));

                progressValue++;    //4
                publishProgress(progressValue);

                // Building the message to the PHP script
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("name" , "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name , "UTF-8")
                        + "&" + URLEncoder.encode("surname" , "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(surname , "UTF-8")
                        + "&" + URLEncoder.encode("age" , "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(age , "UTF-8")
                        + "&" + URLEncoder.encode("username" , "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username , "UTF-8")
                        + "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password" , "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password , "UTF-8");

                progressValue++;    //5
                publishProgress(progressValue);

                // Writing the data
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);

                progressValue++;    //6
                publishProgress(progressValue);

                // Closing all writing structures
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();

                // Building the Reading Infrastructure
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream , "iso-8859-1"));

                // Reading the data
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                // Closing all reading structures
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                progressValue = 10;
                publishProgress(progressValue);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                progressValue = 11;
                publishProgress(progressValue);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        // FOR CHECKING THE PROBLEM WITH CONNECTING TO THE WAMP SERVER
        /*
        int progressValue = values[0];
        // Before IF statement
        if (progressValue == 0) Toast.makeText(this.context , "Before if" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // After IF statement
        if (progressValue == 1) Toast.makeText(this.context , "After if" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // After URL statement
        if (progressValue == 2) Toast.makeText(this.context , "After URL Setting" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Before Writing data
        if (progressValue == 3) Toast.makeText(this.context , "After making HTML" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // After Writing data
        if (progressValue == 4) Toast.makeText(this.context , "After making writing infra" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // After Writing data
        if (progressValue == 5) Toast.makeText(this.context , "Before Writing data" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // After Writing data
        if (progressValue == 6) Toast.makeText(this.context , "After Writing data" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // After Writing data
        if (progressValue == 10) Toast.makeText(this.context , "First exception" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // After Writing data
        if (progressValue == 11) Toast.makeText(this.context , "IO Exception" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        */
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        String subRes = result.substring(0,26); // To cut all the bulshit
        alertDialog.setMessage(subRes);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

edit: here is the Stack Trace (I think , I'm new to Android development so not so sure about where the stack trace should be):

```
  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; regionStart=0; regionLength=26
                                                                                                       at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:583)
                                                                                                       at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1464)
                                                                                                       at com.example.nok_000.mysqlwithandroidproject.BackgroundWorker.onPostExecute(BackgroundWorker.java:246)
                                                                                                       at com.example.nok_000.mysqlwithandroidproject.BackgroundWorker.onPostExecute(BackgroundWorker.java:29)
                                                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
                                                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
                                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank you,
Noam

Comment: crash -> stacktrace.

Comment: Standard security notice: **do not send cleartext passwords over unsecure (http) connections.**

Comment: @njzk2 , I've edited my original post by adding what I think is the stacktrace error.. thank you

Comment: @adelphus this code isn't for real application , it is only for POC but anyway thank you for your comment

Comment: this illustrates well the issue with not handling exceptions and continuing the execution. Your stacktrace is not directly related to the issue. As you can see if you take a second to read the error, your result string is empty. It is empty because nothing is added to it. nothing is added to it either because the server does not answer anything, or because there is another exception before. But since you simply catch and log the exception and then simply continue, you can't see it at first. You have to look higher in your log for another stacktrace .

Comment: @njzk2 Thank you! I found my problem (with the String) and fixed it. now it's cool.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved , the crash was because of not handling correctly some of the String issues (wasnt related to AsyncTask).

Comment: Your problem was in this line
        `String subRes = result.substring(0,26); // To cut all the bulshit`
String wasn't that long and you got IndexOutOfBoundsException, Just fix that line :D I was playing warcraft, couldn't answer, and I knew the answer 20 min ago :D

Comment: @Vucko haha yeah I've fixed it. thank you , you can keep playing this fine game now :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    String subRes = result.substring(0,26); // To cut all the bulshit
```

This line contains the problem because the string `result` is shorter than 26 characters. Check what that is and use substring more carefully.

That's why you're getting the exception, either remove that line or examine it more carefully (do not *hardcore* 26, rather use `indexOf(something)`, where `something` is the thing that marks last thing you wanna keep in your string.)